# Setting td width and ignoring size of contents on variable width table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table which has fixed width td/th elements within a variable width container div.  However the contents of the cells do not overflow as expected.   The text should be stay on a single line (white-space: nowrap) and just be cut off.

In the example below the text in the second column, 1st tbody row should be cut off however it isn't. (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agAgeas50/6gbFd/)).

Html (Css in link above):

```
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
         <th id="idCol">Id</th>
         <th id="descCol"><a>Description</a></th>
         <th class="otherCol">Test</th>
         <th class="otherCol">Test2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>10</td>
         <td>Text that should be cut off because this text is extra long</td>
         <td>a Column</td>
         <td>foo Column </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, if you really want your content to not wrap, you should instead add

```
max-width: 0;
```

to your **td** in the CSS.

It seems that although the **th** has a max-width, the **td** is allowed to get bigger and overrides it.  By giving **td** a max-width also, your new max-width is the MAX of the two max-width's.